# Show that $|\phi(a)| \mid|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G,H$ be groups and $\phi\colon G\to H$ be a one-to-one group homomorphism. Let $a\in G$. Show that $|\phi(a)| \mid |G|$. Not sure how to attack this proof.

Do we use the First Isomorphism Theorem and Lagrange's Theorem? I am unsure if the canonical homomorphism is helpful for this proof.

Comment: Hint: Show that the order of $\phi(a)$ divides that of $a$.

Comment: $\ker \phi$ is trivial so $\text{im}\ \phi \cong G$ and obviously $|\phi(a)| \Big| |\text{im}\ \phi|$.

Comment: @0XLR Do you mind writing a definition of $im\phi$ please? I am confused on I thought that reads image of phi hence would mean $H$, but we are trying to show order of $G$. Is this the same thing since phi is one-to-one?

Comment: As I said, the image of $\phi$ is isomorphic to $G$; so it has the same order as $G$. And yes, that is because of the one-to-one property: the kernel is trivial and the first isomorphism theorem gives $\text{im}\ \phi \cong G$.

Comment: @NormanContreras the definition of $\operatorname{im}\phi$ is $\{ \phi(g) : g \in G\}$.  It is also denoted by $\phi(G)$, and is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: No, the order of $H$ is not necessarily equal to the order of $G$.  Here $\phi$ being one-to-one means that it sends distinct elements of $G$ to distinct elements of $H$ (injective).  It is not necessarily a bijection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi(G) = \{ \phi(g) : g \in G\}$ be the image of $G$ under $\phi$.  It is a subgroup of $H$ (check this), and in particular, $\phi(G)$ is a group.  Because $\phi(G)$ is a group containing the element $\phi(g)$, Lagrange's theorem tells us that the order of $\phi(g)$ divides the order of $\phi(G)$.

Now because $\phi$ is assumed to be one-to-one, what does that tell you about the relationship between the order of $G$ and the order of $\phi(G)$?

Answer (score 5):

By Lagrange, the order of $a$ divides the order of $G$.  By the homomorphism property, the order of $\phi(a)$ divides the order of $a$.  Now by transitivity of divisibility, the result follows.

You don't need injectivity.

However, injectivity could be considered to simplify the proof.  Because $\phi(a)$ will be an element of the image.  Then apply the first isomorphism theorem and Lagrange.